# How do I convert a RACSignal to a SignalProducer in ReactiveCocoa 5?

Tags: objective-c, swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-4, reactive-cocoa-5

In ReactiveCocoa 4, we could convert a `RACSignal` into a `SignalProducer` using `toSignalProducer()`. This method does not exist in ReactiveCocoa 5, so how can we do the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `bridgedSignalProducer()` in [ReactiveObjCBridge](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveObjCBridge):

```
someSignal.toSignalProducer()
```

becomes

```
bridgedSignalProducer(from: someSignal)
```

This produces a `SignalProducer<Value?, AnyError>`. Unlike RAC 4's `startWithNext()`, RAC 5's `startWithValues()` is only on `SignalProducer`s whose `Error` type is `NoError`. To get around this, I added a utility function on `SignalProducer` that behaves the same way as `startWithValues` but works with any `Error` type (ignoring any error.)

Comment: `bridgedSignalProducer` has been superseded. You can now use `SignalProducer`'s `init<SignalValue>(_ signal: RACSignal<SignalValue>)` initializer.

Comment: @user2067021 can you guide me the usage you mentioned in your comment.I am unable to convert it :(

Comment: @Luke or can you guide me :)

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan With ReactiveCocoa 7.0.1 and ReactiveObjcCBridge 2.0.0: `let racSignal = RACSignal<NSDate>()
  let sigProd = SignalProducer(racSignal)`

Comment: Thanks @user2067021 really appreciate your help

Comment: Swift 4 / ReactiveCocoa 7.0.1 / ReactiveObjcCBridge 2.0.0 update
Now it called `SignalProducer(_)`. For example if it was `rac_textSignal().toSignalProducer()` now it looks like: `SignalProducer(rac_textSignal())`